# libxml++ и Qt - ошибки линковщика

Tags: c++, qt

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при компиляции приложения происходит:

> mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ xmlDocGetRootElement в функции "public: void __cdecl MainWindow::searchBalance(void)" (?searchBalance@MainWindow@@QEAAXXZ)

```
void MainWindow::searchBalance()
{
    xmlDocPtr FileXml = xmlParseFile("userstats.xml");
    xmlNodePtr cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(FileXml);

    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while(cur != NULL)
    {
        qDebug() << xmlGetProp(cur, (const xmlChar*)"cash");
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

подключение бибилотеки, из файла .pro

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libxml/lib/ -llibxml2

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libxml/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libxml/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/iconv/lib/ -liconv

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/iconv/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/iconv/include
```

Помогите, не могу понять в чём причина!!!

Comment: Разрядность `libxml2` совпадает с разрядностью приложения?

Comment: скорее всего что нет!

Comment: @LevBazdyrev а разрядность должна совпадать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что разрядность вашего приложения соответствует разрядности подключаемых библиотек, если разрядность различная то естественно ничего не будет работать.

Так же, если вы работаете из под операционной системы Windows и хотите построить х64 приложение, то вам потребуется построить x64 версию QT Creator'a из исходников.

Comment: У меня 64 битная windows но приложение мне надо 32-х битное. И момент второй: у меня ругается на libxml2d.lib но в архиве я так его и не нашёл. Архив с либой взят отсюда... https://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html

Comment: @LevBazdyrev libxml2d.lib 'd' - указывает на то, что вам нужна дебаг версия библиотеки. То есть вам нужно забрать сорцы и сбилдить дебаг версию, либо пропробовать релиз версию.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, проблема решена стандартный парсером!